# Creating bitmaps not working

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap

For some reason my bitmap creation is not working. Have I found a bug? When I try to make a new bitmap using a Matrix, it says my width and height must be over 0 which makes no sense.

```
Bitmap tempbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(image1, 0, 0, newwidth, newheight, matrix, true);
```

I know it might seem like I haven't done any research, I have and it makes no sense. I have tried manythings including changing newwidth and newheight to constants and it still does not work. Here is the stack track trace if that helps

```
11-03 18:32:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(9113): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
11-03 18:32:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(9113):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:603)
11-03 18:32:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(9113):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
11-03 18:32:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(9113):     at com.ajayinkingston.antiverse.Level.tick(Level.java:291)
11-03 18:32:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(9113):     at com.ajayinkingston.antiverse.Logic.tick(Logic.java:65)
11-03 18:32:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(9113):     at com.ajayinkingston.antiverse.GameView.run(GameView.java:142)
11-03 18:32:00.700: E/AndroidRuntime(9113):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I am trying to make a spinning portal. I wanted to have a matrix translate, rotate and scale but I did not get that working. I decided to take out the translation and just make an image and later draw the image. The matrix is created here:

```
matrix.reset();             
matrix.setScale((newwidth)/image1.getWidth(), (newheight)/image1.getHeight());
matrix.postRotate(rotation, image1.getWidth()/2 + x, image1.getHeight()/2 + y);
```

The values of newwidth and newheight do not matter as this error happens with constants.

Comment: So what are the values of image1, newwidth, newheight, and matrix before the call?

Comment: oh sorry completely forgot to add will add right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find out why. So, I decided to do it another way. I removed the `matrix.setScale()` and just used `bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` later.

Answer (score 1):

Checked code of `Bitmap.java`
Those exception happened if  `image1` `width` or`height` is 0.

upd.
or matrix is empty.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#L680

Comment: agree, it's not source. In case of problems with source or width height params there would be different exception text. Looks like problem with matrix.

Comment: I added the matrix loading. Nothing seems to be wrong. Is the reset causing something to go wrong?